# Is it possible to use Mercurial ACL Extension in a Bitbucket repository?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

We have a small team working together with a BitBucket Mercurial repository. The thing is we have a "Releases" branch and want to restrict access to this to just certain people.

I've been looking to the Mercurial ACL extension, but it seems to work just with local repositories.

Do you know any solution for this if everyone pushes directly to Bitbucket?

Thx!

Comment: Subrepo instead of branch? Duplicate content, but **can** work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use the ACL extension with Bitbucket. It would have to be enabled on their servers and they would have to provide a web interface for you to edit the rules. They haven't done this.

What you can do is to use a fork (separate repository) on Bitbucket to store your releases. You can restrict push/pull access on a per-fork basis so this could help you.

An alternative is to let only a few people push to the Bitbucket repository. They would then act as gatekeepers and so they can reject changesets on the wrong branch.

However, restricting access like this is generally not necessary. If it is, then you have a social problem that you should solve by talking with your developers.